# Propagate values in excel cell

Tags: excel, binary, cell

I need to propagate cell values to a row, it's sort of difficult to explain...

I have a cell which is always going to be populated with binary values, for example "01110011"
the number changes according to other formulas.
what I need to do is take similar adjacent values and populate a raw with them...

a picture is worth a thousand words I suppose...

http://s28.postimg.org/mf42j9ftp/223.jpg

So basically I need to take the A1 cell and split it across a row...

and I have no idea what so ever how it's done.

Comment: Where is the programming problem here?

Comment: I populated the cells manually as an example of what I need to do, I just don't know how to do it in excel automatically, the A1 cell is going to change value based on a function it has so it's not going to have a static value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find the `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, and `MID` functions useful. If you were to put all the values that you need to split, like `01110011` (the binary string you used as an example), in column `A`, you could split it in columns `B`, `C`, `D` and `E` with the following formulas:

Column `B`:

```
=LEFT($A1,1)
```

Column `C`:

```
=MID($A1,2,3)
```

Column `D`:

```
=MID($A1,5,2)
```

Column `E`:

```
=RIGHT($A1,2)
```

The `LEFT` function takes a cell as the first argument and the number of characters you want from that cell starting with the leftmost character. The `RIGHT` function does the same but from the rightmost character. The `MID` function takes the cell as the first argument, the index of the character you wish to begin from as the second argument, and the number of characters you wish to return as the third argument.

Comment: The values in the A1 cell are dynamic and will change according to user input, they will always have binary values, only with each calculation they will be different so there is no way of knowing the range of characters that is to be extracted :S

Comment: So you don't know the sizes of the groups you want to break it into?

Comment: What about the example you used tells you that you need to break it apart the way you did in the picture?

Comment: Are you looking to split them into groups of all `1` or all `0`?

Comment: I Posted the picture to better explain what I need to have the end result be, I'm looking to split them so the zeros are separate from  the ones....

Comment: 00111011000 etc ... 

I need to split this cell into separate columns so they would be like this...

A20: 00

A21: 111

A22: 0

A23: 11

A24: 000

Comment: You should modify the question to make that clear. Just because the example happens to show the ones split from the zeroes does not necessarily imply that the binary strings should be split that way.

Comment: Sorry I'm having a hard time explaining things :S

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

```
Sub splitCell()

    Dim cellContent As String
    Dim partOfCell As String
    Dim columnCounter As Integer

    'just to be sure set row format as text to support 00
    Rows(2).ClearContents
    Rows(2).NumberFormat = "@"

    cellContent = CStr(Cells(1, 1))
    columnCounter = 1

    If Len(cellContent) > 0 Then
     partOfCell = Mid(cellContent, 1, 1)
    End If

    For i = 2 To Len(cellContent)
        If Mid(cellContent, i, 1) = Mid(partOfCell, 1, 1) Then
            partOfCell = partOfCell + Mid(cellContent, i, 1)
        Else
            Cells(2, columnCounter) = partOfCell
            partOfCell = Mid(cellContent, i, 1)
            columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Cells(2, columnCounter) = partOfCell

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this option as well,

```html
Sub ListStringIntoB()
'Loop through string, list characters into Starting B1 and over
    Dim str As String, Cnt As Integer, A1 As Range, Lp As Integer
    Dim col As Long, Rng As Range, r As Range

    Set A1 = Range("A1")
    str = A1
    Cnt = Len(A1)
    For Lp = 1 To Cnt
        col = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Set Rng = Cells(1, col)
        Rng = Mid(str, Lp, 1)
    Next Lp
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys for trying to help, I finally found the answer to my predicament... I had to use this code to do the trick..

```
Sub SplitBinaryNumbers()
  Dim Bin As Variant
  Bin = Application.Transpose(Split(Replace(Replace(Range("A8").Value, "01", "0,1"), "10", "1,0"), ","))
  With Range("A20").Resize(UBound(Bin))
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Cells = Bin
  End With
End Sub
```

I hope this helps someone.